# TexMaker: Greek acute next to letter instead of above

Tags: pdftex, texmaker, editors, greek

I'm writing a document in Greek language.

My problem is that the editor sometimes displays the greek acute next to the letter instead of above. This occurs when I change the language to English in my keyboard and then back to Greek **but not always**.

Example given for the right acute position

```
Οι προτάσεις που ικανοποιούνται από την $I$ είναι οι 
$\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3$.
```

Now if I change the language to English and write something and then try to rewrite the same sentence as above

```
Οι προτ´ασεις που ικανοποιο´υνται απ´ο την $I$ ε´ιναι οι
$\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3$.
```

If I compile the two sentences the result is the same but it is really annoying having this kind of code. The problem is solved if I restart TexMaker but usually reoccurs within minutes.

I'm using TexMaker in Debian 8.

Edit: MWE after request

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\title{Τεχνητή Νοημοσύνη}
\author{Εργασία 4\\ }
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*.}]

\item
Χρησιμοποιώ τον όρο \textlatin{grufallo} για να 
περιγράψω τον  \textlatin{grufallo} της
εικόνας και την λέξη \textlatin{littlemouse} 
για να περιγράψω τον ποντίκι της εικόνας.
\begin{enumerate}[label={\roman*.}]
\item
Θα ορίσω μια ερμηνεία $I$ με βάση την οποία το λεξιλόγιο 
των παρακάτω προτάσεων περιγράφει
με ακρίβεια τον κόσμο της εικόνας.\\
\item Οι προτάσεις που ικανοποιούνται από την $I$ είναι οι 
$\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that's U+00B4 so this question is perhaps a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348155/using-utf-and-not-displaying-accent-marks/348182?noredirect=1#comment855299_348182

Comment: not a duplicate very similar though. I get the correct result in the .pdf the problem is the random behavior of the editor

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Which font is used by TeXmaker for the code?

Comment: Strange! It is a unicode font. I really have no idea of what happens.

Comment: the editor can not be saving those characters into the file if pdftex is showing accented characters without further definitions. Odd.

Comment: please show a complete small document with that text that typesets correctly, so we can see what packages are loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only reproduce the issue if I input the accented letter into two different ways:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\textlatin{precomposed}: ώ

\textlatin{combining}: ώ

\end{document}
```

In the first case I typed directly `ώ` (U+03CE), in the second case I typed `ω` (U+03C9) followed by U+0301 (COMBINING ACUTE ACCENT). This site apparently does input normalization, so if you copy the second instance of `ώ` you get U+03CE).

However, `utf8x` and `ucs` raise an error message:

```
! Package ucs Error: Please activate option 'combine'.

See the ucs package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9 \textlatin{combining}: ώ
```

Unfortunately, adding `\usepackage[combine]{ucs}` produces wrong output nonetheless (even worse).

Ensure you only use precomposed glyphs, never combining accents.

Also, it's better not using `utf8x`. With `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` I get

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ́ (U+301)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9 \textlatin{combining}: ώ
```

which informs you where finding the combining character, so to be able to fix it.

Comment: Thanks! I also found your answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc
I changed to [utf8] instead of [utf8x] and I also changed the font to DejaVu Sans instead of DejaVu Sans Mono. This combination seems to work fine for the time being

Comment: Why not to us `XeLaTeX` with a font that supports both latin and greek alphabet, like `Artemisia`, `Linux Libertine`,etc? I believe that `xelatex` and `lualatex` are more suitable when you have to deal with multilingual documents

Comment: @Yorgos The issue (I think) is editor-related rather than distribution-related. I have XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX etc but I use pdftex for simplicity.

Comment: with `xelatex` you can avoid `\textlatin{}` command if you have too many terms in english. Also note that your references  will be presented in greek, since the main language of your document is greek

Comment: @egreg sorry for my unrealated to the question comments